# How do I password protect my printer from other network users?

Tags: networking, printing

I am working in court. There are several ubuntu machines in this network. When I shared my printer in the network I wish only specific computer should be able to print on my printer. But my printer receive print command from several other Ubuntu machines in the network. How can I handle this problem.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your intent, but if you **don't** share the printer, other computers will not be able to access it, but you'll still be able to print to it from your machine.

Comment: I wish mine computer and apart from that one other computer in the network should be able to give command on my printer and not everybody in the network